# Scale iframe to fit?

Tags: css

I want to simulate what a page will look like on another page, such as a web page preview on a little TV.  I use an `<iframe>` for this, and `scale` in CSS to bring it down to a reasonable size.

```
<div class="tv">
  <iframe src="https://example.com"></iframe>
</div>

.tv {
  width: 960px;
  height: 540px;
}

.tv iframe {
  width: 1920px;
  height: 1080px;
  scale: 0.5;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Now, suppose the iframe size can be different, changed with script.  If the iframe width/height become larger, the scale must become smaller.  If the iframe width/height become smaller, the scale must become larger.

Is there a way to set the scale of an item so that it always fits within its container, preserving aspect ratio?  Or must I calculate the scale in script, each time the size of the iframe changes?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css

Comment: You are using scale wrong: `transform: scale(2, 3);`. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Comment: @Alic Thanks, fixed.  I had put the wrong code in the question.

Comment: @ObedMarquezParlapiano Unfortunately, that's not a duplicate.  I need to use `scale` as I need the iframe content to scale down.